# Остается контур от смежных пикселей

Tags: алгоритм, изображения, opencv

Стоит задача распознавания таблицы и выделения из нее элементов в отдельные изображения, для последующего распознавания. Используя threshold добился получения двух таких изображений:

[image: Содержание][image: ]]

Инверсией первого и сложением результата со вторым, получаю следующее:

[image: Содержание][image: ]]

Видно, что буквы затираются не целиком, остаются граничные пиксели.
Подкрутка значений threshold не помогла: либо становится хуже, либо затираются линии. Пытался накостылить - получилась сложность O(n^3), а это никуда не годится.

Подскажите встроенные средства opencv2 или алгоритм, что можно сделать чтобы заполнить смежные пиксели цветом и избавится от этих границ?

Comment: Если нужно сетку без букв получить, то воспользуйтесь `findContours()`, а затем, в цикле рассматривая каждый из найденных контуров, закрашивайте белым цветом только те, что удовлетворяют некоторому условию. Например, размеру буквы.

Comment: "писелей" – ошибка по Фрейду :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- находите пороговеое значение
- найденное значение уменьшаете на некоторое значение X
- все пиксели, яркость которых выше чем ваше полученное значение приравниваете к белому цвету.

---

**Альтернативный метод:** на изображении, где только буквы, расширьте сами буквы. Т.е. если если пиксель (i,j) черного цвета, то закрасьте пиксели (i+x,j+y) |x|+|y|

Теперь на начальном изображении (сетка+буквы) заполняем все пиксели белым цветом если на маске этот пиксель черный.

Comment: Изображение бинаризовано, а даже если нет, все равно на монотонном фоне

Comment: @mersinvald, добавил второй вариант решения.